# Finding electrical force between a charged object and an uncharged object?

Tags: electrostatics

Coulombs law finds force between two charged objects, but what is the force if only one of the objects is charged?

Comment: Why would an uncharged object experience any force at all?

Comment: A charged object does attract uncharged objects eg small pieces of paper, hair.  A charged balloon will stick to an uncharged wall/ceiling.   How can that force be quantified?

Answer (score 2):

Theoretically, if the two objects are point particles, the force is zero as answered by Noiralef.

For real objects, however, there will be a force if the the uncharged object has a finite size. This is because the charge of the other object will repel like charges away and attract unlike charges towards it. For the uncharged object becomes polarized. The unlike charges closer to the charged object will experience a greater attractive force due to Coulomb's law, and the like charges at the other end will experience a smaller repulsive force. Therefore the total force is attractive. This is why a rubbed comb can attract the hair.
[image]

Comment: Can the size of such attractive force be quantified?

Comment: Very difficult, unless you have simple objects, e.g., with good symmetry. For instance, the force between a point charge and an isolated neutral sphere can be calculated analytically.

Answer (score 1):

If one charge is zero, there is no interaction and thus no force. This is in fact included in Coulomb's Law
$$ F \sim \frac{q_1 q_2}{r^2} , $$
if you set $q_1$ or $q_2$ to zero.

Comment: That's what Coulomb's law suggests, but real life experience is that a charged object will attract uncharged objects (eg small pieces of paper, hair, or a charged balloon sticking to wall/ceiling).  Can we quantify the force?

Comment: Those are no point particles, so Coulomb's law doesn't apply. The reason behind the forces that appear in your examples is illustrated in the answer of velut luna, they are called Van der waals forces. Quantitatively, they will obviously depend on properties of the materials.